# Dependency error in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

I'm new to angularjs/js and trying to follow an example in introduction video, but in spite of copying the example, I get errors that does not appear in demonstration video.

The error I get is 'unknown provider routeProvider'.

Can someone explain why I get the error -- and not least how I resolve it?

thanks,

Anders

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script >
    var app = angular.module("app", []);

    app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    });

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ILQOFAgaXE

Comment: specify the dependancy as `angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);`

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem!
;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add this to the `app` dependencies:

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
```

`ngRoute` is a separate module which contains `$routeProvider`

The youtube video is referring to a version of angular prior to `1.2` where when `ngRoute` was present, it was merged with `angular` itself

Comment: Indeed, that did the trick ;)
You were so fast I can't accept your answer yet -- I'll do it in a few minutes...
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

angular route has been moved to a seperate module and you need to download, include angular-route.js in your html file. download the angular-route.js file from here --> https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-route. 
and change this line `var app = angular.module("app", []);`
to `var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);`